# Rollback to Windows 8.1 From Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, windows, wine, windows-8

while trying to install Ubuntu I accidentally wiped out the HDD and now my Windows 8 is gone and I'm trying to install it back whether alongside with Ubuntu or alone.

I downloaded the windows 8.1 ISO and the win-7 USB Dvd tool but of course they're .exe files so I downloaded "wine" but it didn't work and now I'm stuck with ubuntu and the files mentioned above

NOTE: I have an ultrabook so I don't have CD/DVD drive installed which means I'm only capable of using USB-stick
and there's noway that this post is duplicated

Comment: The normal way to install Windows is via a boot-able CD or DVD.  Windows should overwrite any existing OS.  Since you don't have DVD drive you need a boot-able Windows USB.  This is off topic here as its not about Ubuntu but Windows, but you may want to take a look [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/127377/the-best-free-tools-for-creating-a-bootable-windows-or-linux-usb-drive/)

Comment: The Link didn't and won't help as all the tools are for windows and there's only one application that runs on Ubuntu but only to install another Linux-based distribution...anyway thanks

Comment: Try this link [Create A Bootable Windows 7 USB Drive From Linux (Tested On Ubuntu)](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) or find a Windows machine you can temporarily use to create a USB you can then use to install Windows on your machine.

Comment: Was this an UEFI install? And is Ubuntu in UEFI with gpt partitions? Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI, although you can convert back to MBR(msdos) and install in BIOS mode. But if dual booting both systems must be same either UEFI or both BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program that will burn Win 8 to a flash drive that may be better than Unetbootin for you. It is called Win2flash. It is free and it should run under wine easily.
Because you have an iso you will need to mount the iso with a program such as AcetoneISO, Furius ISO Mount, Gmountiso or gISOMount. Acetone may be the easiest for you. you can find them in Ubuntu Software Manager.  You will mount the iso and it will appear as a CD and you can point Win2flash right to it and then it will create an installable windows 8 on your flash drive.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i tried All of these things before your answers and nothing worked because the Whole Ubuntu seemed collapsing unity dash was gone and the pre-installed apps too so i used my brother's PC and managed to make a bootable USB drive and then i changed the BIOS settings then had some problems installing the Windows because it wouldn't accept the GPT Partition so i changed it to MBR Partition and then everything worked fine

Answer (score -1):

hmm, well 1º thing 1º , you cant install windows 8 direct from wine , 2º there is no support to get from linux env to win env, so what you are trying cant be done like that.

get the iso you download to a pen drive, use unetbootin from http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ and make your DVD/PEN-DRIVE install dvd and install you pc using that pen.

Before you do that is beter to make the same to a hirens boot cd ( if you have a spare pen ) for any problems you find, it have a win PE to help you on many things.

Its a good idea to save all data to a ext drive before doing that.

Best regards
Custume